# Error al usar Timestamp en 000webhost

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, hosting, timestamp, host

tengo esta consulta

```
INSERT INTO compra(id,fecha) VALUES(null,DEFAULT)
```

Tengo un proyecto en **000webhost**.
La columna *fecha* es de tipo **TIMESTAMP**, pero al hacerla me sale una dato malos. La fecha si sale bien pero la hora me sale mal.

Por ejemplo mi fecha y hora es: **2021-07-13 21:03:00**

Pero me registra esta: **2021-07-14 02:03:00**

Me la adelanta **5 Horas**.

Soy de México pero me pone la hora como si fuera de Islandia.

En **localhost** si funciona bien, que debo hacer para solucionar eso???

Comment: No, no es la zona horaria de Islandia, realmente es la zona horaria neutra o [UTC](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado). El valor de un dato de tipo [TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) se almacena en dicha zona horaria, para que se muestre correctamente de acuerdo a la configuración local del cliente que la consulte. Lo que debes hacer es usar y trabajar con el valor UTC y aplicar el cambio de zona horaria de acuerdo a la configuración de tu equipo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Segutamente esta recogiendo la alarma de la configuracion del servidor local xampp o wampp x ejemplo .. trata de que utilice el horario que arroja tu pc..